# Visual Studio's "auto-resolve" feature doesn't work for extension methods - what now?

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, extension-methods, intellisense

I love the "Resolve" feature in visual studio.

**Typical scenario:**

1. Type in `Debug`
2. Type `.`
3. Notice that no intellisense appears
4. Right-click
5. Select Resolve
6. Choose `using System.Diagnostics` or `System.Diagnostics.Debug`

Beautiful. Use it all the time.

**Extension method scenario:**

1. Type in `var maxNumber = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}`
2. Type `.`
3. Notice that intellisense brings up array methods but no LINQ extension methods
4. Manually type `Max()`
5. Right-click `Max()`
6. No Resolve to be found
7. Right click on `int[]`
8. Still no Resolve to be found
9. Begrudgingly scroll to the top of the page and enter `using System.Linq;`*

   *assuming you know it by heart, otherwise wrack your brains or try to look it up

**Implementation idea:**

If this feature were to be invented, one idea would be for the first intellisense item that appears when I type `.` to read, `<extension methods...>`, and if I click that item, it brings up a Resolve list of all namespaces that contain extension methods for the class in question.

**Couple questions:**

1. Is this feature slated for future editions of Visual Studio?
2. Any workarounds/tips for finding the extension methods (and the corresponding namespace) that might be available for a particular class?

Comment: ReSharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) already does this with extension methods.

Comment: Does anybody know how it works for VS2012 ?

Answer (score 1):

I really HATE having to "just know" what namespace to use to support any given class.  I mean, there are THOUSANDS OF THEM.  Who knows what namespace you need?  There's no naming convention that can be used as a clue.

It's a shame because I also use Netbeans IDE for Java, and "resolve imports" works flawlessly for everything.

Comment: Does Java even have extension methods?  Like the OP says it works just fine for the typical usage, probably just as flawlessly as in NetBeans IDE for Java.

Comment: There is no extension methods for java. Beside this I also love Eclipse's "organize imports" feature, and importing packages are faster because it automatically imports the packages. Beside this .NET  has many extremely-good features now. I do not want to make an  annoying comparison about it...